# Populate Interactive Report from another interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

There is an interactive Report A with fields: **Name, Position, Salary**. I want another interactive report with information from A with fields **Position and Salary**. Can we do something like

```
select position,sum(salary) from A group by position;
```

I am trying to achieve this without hitting the database twice for 2 interactive reports.

Answer (score 1):

By design the Interactive Reports are a direct query to table or view in the database so each Interactive Report will 'hit the database' so you can't avoid that.

Given that your query 'select position,sum(salary) from A group by position;' has a aggregate and grouping function I assume this is what you really want to avoid as being hard on the database, so what you can do is create a materialized view and that's what you query in your second Interactive Report.